# Plot the real roots of an equation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I wish to plot the real roots of the following equation as a graph of L versus r.

```
L^3 - L*b (P - r) == 0
```

with b=2.6666, P=10, for r in (1,100) with step size 0.1. I have tried the following which does not seem to work.

```
sol = Solve[L^3 - L*b (P - r) == 0, L];
With[{b = 2.6666, P = 10}, Plot[{f[L]}, {r, 1, 100, 0.1}]]
```

How can I plot L (y-axis) versus r (x-axis) for the given range of r?

Comment: Try `ContourPlot`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at your function:

L^3 - L*b (P - r) == 0

One root will certainly be zero. That leaves a quadratic:

```
b = 2.6666;
P = 10;
sol = Solve[L^2 - b (P - r) == 0, L, Reals]
```

[image]

Therefore, there are only real roots for r<10:

```
Plot[L /. sol, {r, -5, 11}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As @cvgmt alluded to in a comment, `ContourPlot` is great for such problems (especially when analytical solutions aren't available).  In your case:

```
b = 2.6666; P = 10;
ContourPlot[L^3 - L*b (P - r) == 0, {r, -10, 20}, {L, -7, 7}, MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image]